# Golang : type By in Go?

Tags: go

This is from Golang.org
http://golang.org/pkg/sort/

```
 // By is the type of a "less" function that defines the ordering of its Planet arguments.
 type By func(p1, p2 *Planet) bool
```

I've never seen this structure. How come func comes after type? And what is type here?

I've seen the following structures but

```
type aaaaaa interface { aaa() string }
type dfdfdf struct { }
```

Never seen like

```
type By func(p1, p2 *Planet) bool
```

How this is possible in Go? type can take other things than interface, struct keywords?

Thanks~!

Comment: Yes. For example it can also take primitive types like `int`. `type` is very similar to the `typedef` keyword in C/C++ except that the arguments are reversed.

Comment: You mean, then func(p1, p2 *Planet) bool is now a type as a whole?

Comment: `func(p1, p2 *Planet) bool` is the declaration of a function pointer in Go. If you can get around the reversed argument/type this is consistent with [the style used by C/C++ `typedef` statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef#Using_typedef_with_function_pointers) to declare function pointers as types.

Comment: It's not a function pointer. It's just a function. Functions in go are first class types and it's not necessary to have a pointer to them. It's also not quite correct to think of these as a typedef. It's full type in go just like type Foo struct{} would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type By func(p1, p2 *Planet) bool` is an example of defining a type from a function value.

We can see that by creating a new `By` value and printing the type using `fmt.Printf`. In the example below I stumped out `Planet` as a string - the type doesn't matter for the purposes of the example.

*type.go*

```
package main
import(
  "fmt"
  )

type Planet string
type By func(p1, p2 *Planet) bool

func main() {
  fmt.Printf("The type is '%T'", new(By))
  fmt.Println()
}
```

Output:

```
mike@tester:~/Go/src/test$ go run type.go
The type is '*main.By'
```

EDIT: Updated per nemo's comment. The [`new`](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_new) keyword returns a pointer to the new value. `func` does not return a function pointer like I had incorrectly thought but instead returns a function value.

Comment: `*func()` is a pointer to a function value. `func()` is just a function value. The term function pointer originates in C and should not be used for a function value in go IMO.

Comment: @nemo - You're right. I've updated the answer to reflect your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new type in go with any base type including another user defined type.

For instance if you define a new type File

```
type File struct {}
```

with some methods

```
func (f *File) Close() { ... }

func (f *File) Size() { ... }
```

You could then define a new type called:

```
type SpecialFile File
```

and define your own different methods on it.

```
func (f *SpecialFile) Close() { (*File)(f).Close() }
```

The important thing to note is the SpecialFile type doesn't have a Size method on it even though it's base type is a File. You have to cast it to a *File in order to call the Size method.

You can do this for types you don't even own if you want that aren't even in the same package.